# solr.TrieDateField changing the format of date when date ends with 000 mil seconds

Tags: java, solr

Is there a way to make Solr not cut off the trailing mil seconds of a date when using solr.TrieDateField and the trailing time is 000?

If a save a date field with the value: 2013-09-19T15:29:06.576Z It saves as stated. If I save a field with the date 2013-09-19T15:29:06.000Z it is saved as 2013-09-19T15:29:06Z in the solr document. Is there a way to make it store it as 2013-09-19T15:29:06.000Z?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No way. I've just read in the documentation, that trailing zeros are not accepted. From the Documentation at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates:

> You can optionally include fractional seconds if you wish, although trailing zeros are not allowed and any precision beyond milliseconds will be ignored